# how to play video from htp url in iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to play the video from url in iphone app but it does not play in the app i am using following code

```
-(IBAction)play
{
     NSString*videoFilepath=@"http://myserver.com.pk/Specticle_Revision_v1.mov";
     NSLog(@"Filepath is: %@", videoFilepath);
     NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoFilepath];   
     MPMoviePlayerController *movie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playbackFinishedCallback:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:movie];
     [movie play];
}
```

Comment: NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString: videoFilepath];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myserver.com.pk/Specticle_Revision_v1.mov"];
MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                 selector:@selector(moviePlaybackDidFinish:)
                                     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                   object:mp];    

mp.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];
[mp release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this:

```
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoFilepath];
```

Is your problem.  Your "http://" - style URL is not a file URL.  File URL's (on the local device / file system) begin with "`file:///`".

Try:

```
NSURL * videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString: videoFilepath];
```

and see if that works better.